# How can I apply ground overlay and markers together in React Native map?

Tags: react-native

How can I apply ground overlay and markers together in React Native map?

I want to have some markers above the overlay and the overlay above map.

Answer (score 1):

The [react-native-maps](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps) project is a very capable and active community solution that can handle this.

Here's an example that draws a polygon overlay and places a marker on the overlay:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <MapView
        style={{flex:1}}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 40.758242,
          longitude: -73.848986,
          latitudeDelta: 0.001,
          longitudeDelta: 0.01,
        }}
      >
        <MapView.Polygon
          coordinates={[
            { latitude: 40.757966, longitude: -73.847704 },
            { latitude: 40.758421, longitude: -73.845129 },
            { latitude: 40.756869, longitude: -73.844227 },
            { latitude: 40.755471, longitude: -73.846266 }
          ]}
          fillColor="rgba(0,0,255,0.2)"
          strokeColor="orange"
          strokeWidth={2}
        />
        <MapView.Marker
          title="Citi Field"
          description="center field"
          coordinate={{ latitude: 40.757405, longitude: -73.845815 }}
          pinColor="blue"
        />
      </MapView>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible having a image ground overlay?

Comment: I have found a long times. seems no solution for image overlay and image marker together